# How can I disable button submit for few seconds on server-side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I create client side for disable button on few seconds, but I need that on server side, I do this on client side but that's not working fine for me. Here is code which i try to perform. On this web app work 5 employee and I want to disable button for 3 sec when first of them click, in my solution I have a problem with that when two of them click on same time it generate same idCodes.

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateCodes", "Codes", FormMethod.Post))
   {
  <div class="box-header">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
  <!--Disable button for about 3 second after click button-->
   <button type="submit" id="ok"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="return DisplayProgressMessage(this, 'Saving...');">Generate</button>
   <script>
   function DisplayProgressMessage(ctl, msg) {
   $(ctl).prop("disabled", true);
   $(ctl).text(msg);
   return true;
   }
   </script>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  }
```

In `Html.BeginForm` I using `Codes.cs` which is my controller and I have already defined GenerateCodes in that controller

```
    // GET: /Codes/GenerateCodes
    public ActionResult GenerateCodes(FormCollection collection)
```

Comment: Code synchronization seems to be the solution here. You can use `Monitor.TryEnter` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.tryenter?view=net-5.0) right on top of your method body (optionally with a timespan) to wait for the first user's request to be completed, and the second user's request would execute afterwards, or, you can return an error to the second user if the lock cannot be acquired (when Monitor.TryEnter returns false), telling him that another operation is in progress

Comment: @OguzOzgul How can I do that, can you provide me sa sample of code, I never use synchronization code.

Comment: As I mentioned. If you can read the article on `Monitor` class, you can see how to achieve it. `Monitor.TryEnter()` (or just a simple `lock()`). If you use `Monitor.TryEnter()`, you should also release the lock with `Monitor.Exit()`